# Debian encrypted home directory setup fails

Tags: ssh, debian, encryption, ecryptfs

Here's the problem:

```
# ecryptfs-migrate-home -u <user>
INFO:  Checking disk space, this may take a few moments.  Please be patient.
INFO:  Checking for open files in /home/<user>
Enter your login passphrase [<user>]: 

************************************************************************
YOU SHOULD RECORD YOUR MOUNT PASSPHRASE AND STORE IT IN A SAFE LOCATION.
  ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
THIS WILL BE REQUIRED IF YOU NEED TO RECOVER YOUR DATA AT A LATER TIME.
************************************************************************

Done configuring.

chown: cannot access ‘/dev/shm/.ecryptfs-<user>’: No such file or directory
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
ERROR:  Could not mount
```

This was done over an SSH session.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done over SSH.
From experience, has to be done from a terminal (i.e. Alt+F1) as suid root.

[Discussed on askubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543989/ubuntu-14-04-1-encrypt-home-directory)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this over ssh, but directly. If you login as a root it works. If you try over sudo su - problem persists.

Comment: Did you mean: It is possible to encrypt your user home over ssh, but only if you do this directly with root. If you try over `sudo su -` the problem will persist.